# Can someone look at code to see if I'm missing anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am trying to run this code for a scraper I built but I keep getting a syntax error message: unexpected identifier. Could someone help me see what I put in by mistake? or did I not close something? I am trying to build a scraper that will extract the countries that these foreign films are from.

Here is my code

```
var util = require("util"),
   async = require("async"),
 config = require(__dirname + "/config.js"),
  _ = require("lodash"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
   request=require("request"),
   models = require(__dirname + "/models/index.js").models.autoLoad();


/* BEGIN SCRAPER HERE */
var request = require('request'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "http://www.imdb.com/list/ls057160363/";

request(url, function ( err, resp, code) {
 var $ = cheerio.load(code);

    request(url, function ( err, resp, code) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(code);
      console.log(url);
        $(".info").each(function() {
          var a = $(this).find("a").eq(0);
          var title = a.text();
          var url = "https://www.imdb.com/" + a.attr("href");

            request(url, function(err, body, code) {details page
              var $ = cheerio.load(code);
               console.log(url);
              var country = $('#titleDetails.txt-block a').html();
              var country = $("#titleDetails div").first().text().trim().split(":");
              var country = $("#titleDetails div").eq(0).text().trim().split(":");
              //check if not empty
              console.log(country);
              if( country.length )
                if(country[0] == "Country")
                  country = country[1].trim();
                else{
                  country = $("#titleDetails div").eq(1).text().trim().split(":");
                  console.log(country);
                  if( country.length )
                    country = country[1].trim();
                  else
                    country = ""
                  };
```

And here is the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at createScript (vm.js:80:10) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10) at Module._compile (module.js:588:28) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10) at Module.load (module.js:545:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10) at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16) at bootstrap_node.js:607:3

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add the error message in the post.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @vibhor1997a This is the error message

Comment: ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:607:3

Comment: Is `details page` supposed to be a comment in this line: `request(url, function(err, body, code) {details page`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var util = require("util"),
    async = require("async"),
    config = require(__dirname + "/config.js"),
    _ = require("lodash"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    request = require("request"),
    models = require(__dirname + "/models/index.js").models.autoLoad();


/* BEGIN SCRAPER HERE */
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "http://www.imdb.com/list/ls057160363/";

request(url, function (err, resp, code) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(code);

    request(url, function (err, resp, code) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(code);
        console.log(url);
        $(".info").each(function () {
            var a = $(this).find("a").eq(0);
            var title = a.text();
            var url = "https://www.imdb.com/" + a.attr("href");

            request(url, function (err, body, code) {
                //details page
                var $ = cheerio.load(code);
                console.log(url);
                var country = $('#titleDetails.txt-block a').html();
                var country = $("#titleDetails div").first().text().trim().split(":");
                var country = $("#titleDetails div").eq(0).text().trim().split(":");
                //check if not empty
                console.log(country);
                if (country.length)
                    if (country[0] == "Country")
                        country = country[1].trim();
                    else {
                        country = $("#titleDetails div").eq(1).text().trim().split(":");
                        console.log(country);
                        if (country.length)
                            country = country[1].trim();
                        else
                            country = ""
                    }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You had missed several brackets at the end and "details page" which was supposed to be a comment was not a comment.